# Can the closedness condition for $H$ be removed?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

[image]

In Theorem 7.35, if we remove the closedness condition for $H$, we also can prove the map $(n,h)\mapsto nh$ is a Lie group isomorphism between $N\rtimes_{\theta}H$ and $G$, then $H$ is a closed Lie subgroup of $G$.

What I said is correct?

Comment: Posting extended scans and screenshots isn't great. It's not searchable or accessible. Would you be able to replace the scan with the relevant part typed in $\LaTeX$?

Comment: Also, from what source is this? Please give credit where credit is due...

Comment: @Vincent Lee's "Introduction to Smooth manifolds".

Comment: @JackLee What I said is correct?

Comment: Are there examples where $H$ is not closed? I suspect that the other conditions imply $H$ has to be closed.

Comment: @quarague I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. This was an oversight on my part. Thanks for pointing it out. I've added a correction to my [online list](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/ISM/).

Comment: Does $N$ not need to be closed in $G$?

Comment: You needn't make any change here.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343287/is-h-closed-in-g

Comment: Below Theorem 7.35, you give the definition of internal semidirect product of $N$ and $H$, so I think it is better to give the closedness condition for $H$.

Comment: @Borntobeproud: In the answer to the MathOverflow question you linked to, I think the assumption that $N$ is closed is needed only to conclude that it's $\sigma$-compact and locally compact. But this is true of any manifold, so it's true of $N$ with its Lie subgroup structure even if $N$ is not closed. And in the smooth category, we have much more powerful tools such as the equivariant rank theorem (Thm. 7.25 in my book).

Comment: If $N$ is not closed in $G$, then it is not an embedded submanifold of $G$, then how to show $\theta: H\times N\to N$ is smooth?

Comment: @Borntobeproud: The assumption is that $N$ is a Lie subgroup, which means it has a topology and smooth manifold structure making it into a Lie group and an immersed submanifold. Then $H\times N$ obtains the product smooth manifold structure, and $\theta$ is smooth with respect to that structure.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385132/how-to-show-theta-h-times-n-to-n-defined-by-thetah-n-hnh-1-is-smooth

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385200/is-m-to-fm-also-a-smooth-map

Comment: @Borntobeproud: If $S\subseteq G$ is an immersed submanifold, and $f: N\to G$ is a smooth map whose image happens to lie in $S$, then in general $f$ might not be smooth as a map into $S$. However there is a class of immersed submanifolds, called _**weakly embedded**_ submanifolds, characterized by the property that any such map is also smooth as a map into $S$. Leaves of foliations and immersed Lie subgroups are always weakly embedded. This is explained in my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_: pages 112-114, Thm. 19.17, and Thm. 19.25.

Comment: @Borntobeproud: (But you don't need the theory of weakly embedded submanifolds to prove Thm. 7.35.)

Comment: @JackLee I'm also confused by this part in the argument, showing that the action $\theta: H \times N \to N$ is smooth. It is straightforward to show that it is smooth if the codomain is $G$, but since $N$ is only assumed to be immersed, not embedded, it doesn't follow immediately that $\theta$ is smooth. I don't see how $N$ being closed helps, and we can't yet use Theorem 19.25. We'd need to show that $\theta$ is continuous as a map into $N$ somehow.

Comment: Ah nevermind I get it now, it follows from Theorem 7.21 that if $N$ is closed, it is in fact embedded!