# How to show $\theta: H\times N\to N$ defined by $\theta(h,n)=hnh^{-1}$ is smooth?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Every smooth manifold is assumed to be Hausdorff and second-countable.

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group, and $N,H\subset G$ are Lie subgroups such that $N$ is normal, $N\cap H=\{e\}$, and $NH=G$, where $NH=\{ab:a\in N, b\in H\}$.

How to show $\theta: H\times N\to N$ defined by $\theta(h,n)=hnh^{-1}$ is smooth?

Comment: @JackLee Could you give a proof?

Comment: @YCor Could you give a proof?

Answer (score 0):

By definition of Lie group, $G$ is a smooth manifold such that it’s differentiable structure is compatible with the operation of groups, so for each $g\in G$ the map

$\phi_g: G\to G$ that maps $h$ to $h \cdot g$ is smooth, $\psi$ that maps $h$ to $h^{-1}$ is smooth and the operation of group $\cdot : G\times G\to G$ is also a smooth map.

We consider the map $ (\cdot|_{H\times N}, \psi|_{H}) :H\times N\to G\times G$

that map each $(h,n)$ to $(hn, h^{-1})$.

This map is clearly smooth and your map is exactly

$\theta=\cdot\circ  (\cdot|_{H\times N}, \psi|_{H})$

that is a composition of smooth maps, so it’s a smooth map.

Comment: But the codomain is $N$, not $G$, we don't say $N$ is an embedded Lie subgroup of $G$.

Comment: It is not important, if a map $F: M\to T$ is smooth and it's image is a smooth manifold then it is smooth also in the it's image.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385200/is-m-to-fm-also-a-smooth-map

Comment: "if a map $F: M\to T$ is smooth and it's image is a smooth manifold then it is smooth also in the it's image."   How to prove it?